# Anonymous CallerId and (Un)conditional Forwarding with Twilio

Tags: twilio

When forwarding calls to a twilio number using **unconditional** forwarding from a mobile phone like this:

*21*0031123456789#

I never get information about the original caller id, or better, I get **+266696687** which is the equivalent for ANONYMOUS.

This is a sample of the request parameters that twilio sends

/twilioml?AccountSid=AC9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ToZip=&FromState=&Called=**%2B31123456789**&FromCountry=LS&CallerCountry=LS&CalledZip=&Direction=inbound&FromCity=&CalledCountry=NL&CallerState=&CallSid=CAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&CalledState=&From=**%2B266696687**&CallerZip=&FromZip=&ApplicationSid=APxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&CallStatus=ringing&ToCity=&ToState=&To=**%2B31123456789**&ToCountry=NL&CallerCity=&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&Caller=**%2B266696687**&CalledCity=

If I try a  **conditional** call forwarding like this one for example:

*61*0031123456789#

/twilioml?AccountSid=AC9xxxxxxxx&ToZip=&FromState=&Called=**%2B31123456789**&FromCountry=NL&CallerCountry=NL&CalledZip=&Direction=inbound&FromCity=&CalledCountry=NL&CallerState=&CallSid=CAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&CalledState=&From=**%2B315555555**&CallerZip=&FromZip=&ApplicationSid=APxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&CallStatus=ringing&ToCity=&ToState=&To=**%2B31123456789**&ToCountry=NL&CallerCity=&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&Caller=**%2B315555555**&CalledCity=

In this case, assuming that my number is **+315555555**, the caller id information is my own number and not the original number that called my phone

I'm trying this from Vodafone Netherlands but I haven't tried with another operator yet.
Is there anyway to make this work? Is it a Vodafone (Netherlands) issue or something at the Twilio side because otherwise I'm afraid this is a major setback to our solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this example: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward ?

If that also fails, there's something wrong with the entire process, potentially related to your phone number or carrier.

If it does work, there's probably an error in your TwiML. Would you be able to share the underlying code? Or at least whatever is generated?

Either way, we should be a little closer to the underlying problem. :)

Comment: There's no TwiML involved in the process, it's the operator that forwards the call from my number to the twilio number using a standard GSM call forwarding code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding). Twilio will then call the URL assigned to the Twilio Application to generate TwilioML but it doesn't seem to be sending the original caller ID and what I'm wondering is if this is a Vodafone related issue or a Twilio issue or if there's another way to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: On the Twilio side of things, can you look at your Call Logs and see what number we're getting from the carrier? The info is available here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls

Comment: Doesn't look good, "From: +266696687" And the number I'm calling from is definitely not private so I'm really stuck now wether it's a Twilio issue or a Vodafone issue the solution I'm building is useless without having information from the original caller when forwarding a call

Full Call Log:

CALL SID
CA9e786dfa9f1b9de6a34b57d040520fd4
DATE
05:39:25 PDT 2013-05-22
DIRECTION
Incoming
STATUS
Completed
FROM
+266696687
TO
+3185888XXXX
TYPE
Phone
START TIME
05:39:25 PDT 2013-05-22
END TIME
05:39:53 PDT 2013-05-22
DURATION
1
COST
-$0.01
CALL SEGMENT SID
---

Answer (score 0):

According to Twilio it's an operator issue